# Iphone 5s screen recording via reflector and airplay

Tags: macos, ios, airplay

I'm trying to record my iPhone screen via reflector and airplay but I couldn't find the airplay symbol in my control center if I swipe from bottom to top. There is only airdrop no airplay.

OS: iOS 8.2

Device: iPhone 5s

Recorder Device: Mac Book Pro

Recorder OS: 10.10.2

Comment: Why not connect the iPhone via cable? Then you can record your iPhone's screen in QuickTime on your Mac like a normal camera.

Comment: yes that did solved my problem

Comment: Ok, I just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can record your iPhone screen in OS X if you connect your iPhone with your Mac via cable. You can then select your iPhone as an input device in QuickTime (or any other recording software).
**Note:** This will only work if your iOS device has at least iOS 8 and your Mac has at least OS X 10.10